# THREE.CSS3DRenderer disappeared?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to build something like a HUD in Three.js --

the thing is, I need this HUD to be able to show dynamically updated DOM elements and also respond to drag & drop events inside of my Three.js scene.

I just discovered the CSS3DRenderer, and it looks like the perfect solution, however when I try to implement it, CSS3DRenderer doesn't seem to exist anymore.  I checked the migration logs and there is no mention of removal.

(It seems to have dropped around revision 77, at the same time that the ShadowMaterial appeared, which I am also using heavily, so I don't intend to use an earlier revision.)

So my questions are:

Is this simply a naming issue, and the CSS3DRenderer object still exists in the library?

If not, is there an alternative in Three.js that will allow rendering 'dynamic' DOM elements (and possibly iframes) within a Three.js scene that will also register a collision from a ray?

here is my implimentation:

```
var m = new THREE.ShadowMaterial();
var r = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is (and always has been afaik) in the `examples/js/renderers` folder.
Take a look at r83 on [github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/r83/examples/js/renderers)
You must include this file specifically

Comment: Perfect -- Thanks for the help!